# How to pass correctly( and beautifully) an onChange event to my Redux Store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im building a Betting aplication where the user inputs some predictions for Soccer Games.

My app have a array of matches in my Redux store. Like this:

```
matches:{{id:1, away_result:0, home_result:0, ...}}
```

So, I have a Matchlist Container that reads this data from my store and passes each one as props for a Match Component. My Match component has something like that:

```
 <TextField value={this.props.game.home_result} onChange={this.homeScoreChangedHandler}/>
```

I want that in each onChange event of my TextField my data on the Redux Store to be updated.

For example: My bet is **Brazil 1x0 Argentina**. I want to, when I change the TextField and input "1", an action is dispatched and update my store:

```
matches:{{id:1, away_result:0, **home_result:1**, ...}}
```

But I dont know how to pass it correctly because at my homeScoreChangedHandler I dont have acess to the "this.props.game" property.

Does anyone have any idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: How is homeScoreChangedHandler defined? If you defined it simply as a `function homeScoreChangedHandler() {...}` and didn't use `bind`, then it won't have access to `this`. If instead you define it with `homeScoreChangedHandler = () => {...}`, it will now be able to access `this`, including `props` and all that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to your onchange method.
Something like:

```
 <TextField value={this.props.game.home_result} 
 onChange={(event) => {this.homeScoreChangedHandler(event)}} />

 //method to trigger action creator 
  homeScoreChangedHandler(event.target.value){
 this.props.nameofActionCreator(event.target.value)
 this.methodToUpdateTextField(event.target.value)
  }
```

You would need to update the component with the new props. You can use the react lifecycle method 'componentWillReceiveProps' or by using a callback method and set the component state to from the redux store (via reference to this.props.storeObject that you would set up in your mapStateToProps section). Your biggest issue is going to be avoiding async issues where the store doesn't update fast enough for your data to update.

So I would do some conditional rendering/ use a Promise to control rendering.

In pseudo code:

```
if (this.state.userInput != this.props.game.home_result){
update the react state to the props and render the new data }
else { don't update and just return the current state}
```